# one Column with multiple where conditions

Tags: sql, case, conditional-statements

Can I use Case statement for the below multiple conditions. The output should be one column where all the below conditions should be true. If its true then print 'X' else NULL. I am using SQL server and not sure how I can achieve using Case statement.

```
WHERE 
(
    (D.Type = 'abc') 
    AND D.Status = 'C'
) 
AND 
(
    (
    AAD.D01 IS NOT NULL 
    OR AAD.D02 IS NOT NULL 
    OR AAD.D03 IS NOT NULL 
    OR AAD.D04 IS NOT NULL 
    OR AAD.D05 IS NOT NULL 
    OR AAD.D06 IS NOT NULL 
    OR AAD.D07 IS NOT NULL 
    OR AAD.D08 IS NOT NULL
    ) 
AND (AAD.B05 = 1) 
OR (AAD.B06 = 1)
)
 THEN 'X', ELSE '' END AS [Adjusted]
```

Comment: ...and what is your actual question?  Is there a problem with this `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Please do not post partial queries.

Comment: Post the full code too many mistakes are there.. Logical mistakes are do to missing `Parenthesis`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms188336(v=sql.110).aspx), which can be used within `CASE` clause.

There is very simple example:

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE (Id int)
INSERT INTO @table1 VALUES (1), (2), (6), (10)
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * 
                     FROM @table1 
                     WHERE Id = 1 OR Id = 2) 
       THEN 'X' ELSE '' END AS [Adjusted]
```

Replace

```
SELECT * 
   FROM @table1 
   WHERE Id = 1 OR Id = 2
```

with your actual statement. If it is not what you want to do, update your question and provide full code and more information.

Comment: I was not aware that we could use Exists within case statement good to know thank you, I will try this method and see if it works.

Comment: Exists within Case is what i needed and it worked like a charm. Thank you Rokuto:)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest linq 
You Need a Collection where you can save your data

```
    var datalist = db.Table.Where(d=>d.Type == 'abc').Where(d=>d.Status=='C').Where(AAD=>AAD.D01 != null)......
```

Comment: This question is for `SQL` not C# with Linq